# Compile file containing java and scala code

Tags: scala

Ìs it possible to compile file that contains both scala and java code?
I'm doing online course and was given java source files, which I need to extend. Do I have to use only Java in already existing files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot have both Java and Scala in one file. After all it's either `.java` or `.scala`.

However you are free to:

- extend Java classes in Scala (and vice-versa)
- implement Java interfaces in Scala (syntax is the same as for extending traits)
- extend Scala traits in Java (syntax is the same as for implementing Java interfaces)

...as long as they are in different files.