# Include java source in scala file

Tags: java, scala, compilation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compile file containing java and scala code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443863/compile-file-containing-java-and-scala-code)

I'm aware that Scala can easily use Java classes. However, is it possible to include Java source inside a scala file and have it compile with scalac, in any way?

Alternatively, is it possible to include javac-compiled bytecode as a bytearray in the source, and import from it (yuck, yes)?

This is for homework, so, no, I can't have separate files, and it **must** compile with `scalac file.scala`, with no additional arguments. To clarify, this is a hard requisite by my teacher

Comment: The solution is to learn and write some Scala.

Comment: No. You can't. Please, post why you need them in the same file (besides "it's homework").

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Indeed, and I'm sure I'd learn a lot. It's just that I don't really have the time to fully understand, implement and test a kd-tree library by myself right now, and since efficiency is not one of the central homework requirements, I'd rather have O(n^2) if I can't find one

Comment: it's still unclear where does requirement of having java and scala code in the same file come from. Every popular scala build tool support joint compilation of .scala and .java files.

Comment: @EmilIvanov Well, it's a requirement because my teacher has made it so, I guess? I realise it's a pretty arbitrary one, especially since we *can* use external libraries, as long as we include them in the file

Comment: Did you really intend to suck in the source code of a whole **library** into a single Scala file??

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik indeed. I know it's completely nuts, but my teacher has OK'd it, and won't budge on the single-scala-file requirement. I think he doesn't want to change his grading scripts...

Comment: @om-nom-nom Almost. I'd still like to know if there's any viable way to import from bytecode in a bytearray (or similar)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to write a literal byte array in Scala code, it is easy to go from that to a normal Java class, simply by calling [`Classloader.defineClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass%28java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29). This means that you need to make your own subclass of `ClassLoader` that exposes one of the overloads of this method. This is all doable in Scala without much trouble.

If you carefully prepare this, you may even get type safety, by making your class-from-bytearray implement an interface that you have defined in Scala. I don't know the exact details on this, but I remember it was possible for a Java class to subclass/implement something defined in Scala. Failing that, you certainly have reflection at your disposal.

Comment: This seems *very* promising!

Answer (score 3):

I just wrote a simple example

say you have a java class like this

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

Then you write some scala code to turn that into a byte array

```
import java.io.{FileInputStream, FileOutputStream}
import collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

val in = new FileInputStream("HelloWorld.class")
val out = new FileOutputStream("HelloWorldBytes.scala")

Console.withOut(out) {
  var data = in.read()
  print("val helloWorldBytes = Array[Byte](")
  print(if(data < 128) data else data - 256)
  data = in.read()
  while(data >= 0) {
    print(", ")
    print(if(data < 128) data else data - 256)
    data = in.read()
  }
  println(")")
}


in.close()
out.close()
```

And then you can use it like this

```
val helloWorldBytes = Array[Byte](...)

object Loader extends ClassLoader {
  override
  def findClass(name: String): Class[_] =
    if(name == "HelloWorld") defineClass(name, helloWorldBytes, 0, helloWorldBytes.size)
    else super.findClass(name)
}

val helloWorld = Loader.loadClass("HelloWorld")
helloWorld.getDeclaredMethod("main", classOf[Array[String]]).invoke(null,null)
```

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/manual.html) and specify a Javac-derived [instruction list](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/generic/InstructionList.html) in the Scala, but I can't really imagine how this is practical in any way. The simplest way to do what you want is to use (say) the Maven scala plugin to compile both Java and Scala files together.

Comment: If I understoo what BCEL does in my quick skim, wouldn't this shift the work of implementing the original library in scala to implementing BCEL? Also, I can't send compiled code, only a single scala source. But I pretty much predicted this would be impossible

Comment: @scala_newbie it's impossible to achieve on source-file level

Comment: @om-nom-nom *theoretically*, wouldn't it be possible if there was a scala implementation of the JVM? Of course, I'm not expecting anyone to have a motive for implementing such a thing, it seems pretty pointless

Comment: @scala_newbie I don't think language in which implemented JVM (it's mostly C/C++ as far as I know) somehow affect this issue

Comment: @om-nom-nom What I meant is you could have a JVM running inside another JVM. The base JVM would, of course, be the OS's, the other, implemented in scala, would be free to execute any arbitrary bytecode, including the library bytecode

Comment: @scala_newbie [VM inside VM](http://applejack.ponychan.net/chan/files/src/134854337706.jpg) ;-)

Comment: @scala_newbie exactly xD